# Store JSON Data (get from .txt file) in Database

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

**I am new at iPhone Development.**

I know how to store `JSON` data in database. **But in my case** I have `.txt file` which contain data of  `JSON`. This `.txt file` i get by send request on Server and i got it as .zip file  and after i did it as unzip file  so after i get it as .txt file with JSON data. I get this data from `.txt` file but i dont know how to store it in database.I want to stor this data in DATABASE. How cant i do anybody as idea ???

**Data of .txt file of JSON (*Display in Console*)**

> "Ok","last_response_date":"2013-02-05 00:04:14","**region_master**":[{"id":"1","region_name":"Auckland and Kermadec","border_coordinate_file":"","created_date":"2013-02-01 05:22:42","updated_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"2","region_name":"Central","border_coordinate_file":"","created_date":"2013-02-01 05:22:42","updated_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"3","region_name":"Challenger","border_coordinate_file":"","created_date":"2013-02-01 05:22:57","updated_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"4","region_name":"Fiordland","border_coordinate_file":"","created_date":"2013-02-01 05:22:57","updated_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"5","region_name":"South East","border_coordinate_file":"","created_date":"2013-02-01 05:23:15","updated_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"6","region_name":"Southland","border_coordinate_file":"","created_date":"2013-02-01 05:23:15","updated_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}],
>       "**region_kml_files**":
>         [{"id":"4","region_id":"2","kml_files":"Sample.kml","created_date":"2013-01-25 09:04:58","updated_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]

**EDIT :**

---

I already got data from `.txt file`

---

please help me..
Thanks :)

Comment: "I want to store this data in a database."  This tells us nothing.  Do you just want to store the string as it is?  Do you want to break it into categories and store those?  Be more specific.

Comment: @borrrden not.. in my .txt file (JSON data) multiple has categories(array of dictionary) and i want to store it as categories wise ..

Comment: Good start, now tell us which part you are having trouble with...parsing JSON or inserting into a database.  Don't say both...that is too broad for one question.

Comment: i can't understand what is it... i only know ..in my database 2 table (region_master and region_kml_files) then how can i extract data base on key ??

Comment: You aren't making sense...try to organize your thoughts and be more specific on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @borrrden - see my consol output in question.. i get .txt file can covert it to string (that display in consol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you are having trouble, but it seems like you haven't gotten a JSON object from your string yet, so I will let you know how to do that.  If you need to know how to create and store data in a database, then you need to make a new question and say that you got JSON data but are having trouble storing it into a database (at least make an effort to try to do it though).

You can use `NSJSONSerialization` to get an object out of your string (the `NSData` version of your string, at least).  It will look like this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

If it doesn't work then your JSON is not valid.  Validate it at http://www.jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 NSString *jsonString  = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:yourFilePath encoding:UTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Here:

`yourFilePath` is a NSString which contains the exact path to the .txt file.

You get the file content in `jsonString` variable, you need to save that string to database.

Refer [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) class for more

Comment: and i already get data from .txt file but see this data in my question  (consol output)how can i sore it ??? and thanks for helping

Comment: `UTF8StringEncoding` not `UTF8String`. Please change that